# Why Is This AJAX Request Failing

Tags: ajax, spring-mvc, controller

this is my first time trying to implement AJAX and I haven't been able to figure out why its failing. Apologies, as it's probably easy enough spot for a seasoned AJAX user. I'd appreciate if you took a look.

JQuery File:

```
//declare variables
var friendSearch;
var csrfHeader = "[[${_csrf.headerName}]]";
var csrfToken = "[[${_csrf.token}]]";

$(document).ready(function(){
    //give variables values
    friendSearch = $("#friendSearchBox");
    
    //call functions when
    $(friendSearch).on('input', function(){
        updateFriendsDisplay();
    })
});

//functions
function updateFriendsDisplay(){
    var jsonData = {searchString: friendSearch.val()}
    
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'http://localhost:8080/friends/search',
        beforeSend: function(xhr){
            xhr.setRequestHeader(csrfHeader, csrfToken);
        },
        data: JSON.stringify(jsonData),
        contentType: 'application/json'
    }).done(function(data){
        alert(data);
    }).fail(function(){
        alert("failed");
    });
}
```

Controller:

```
@ResponseBody
@PostMapping("/search")
public List<UserAccount> getFriendsBySearch(@RequestParam("searchString") String text){
    List<UserAccount> accountsList = uRepo.findByUserNamePortion(text);
    return accountsList;
}
```

Comment: Does the Controller work when you hit it directly, like from Postman or a test non-AJAX page? First step would be to isolate whether it's the Controller or the AJAX that is failing.

Comment: @dbreaux I got it working. I'm using spring boot and had a few problems with Spring Security and csrf protection but all good now. Thanks for replying all the same